# repeating letters in java (multiply)

Tags: java, string, char, int

i have a task to repeat characters multiplying it  for example the user should write the letter and number of repeat input 3 R output

```
RRR
```

input 6 O output

```
OOOOOO
```

and it should be one letter only
i have used strings but can i use char ? and how can i do it ? 
why when when multiplying chars the result is number ?
for example char*3 the result is 246

i am new to java

Answer (score 3):

A `char` is represented by a UTF-16 value (an unsigned short).  When you use `char` in arithmetic, its UTF-16 value is used.

If you want to repeat a `char`, you can use something like this:

```
String.join("", Collections.nCopies(6, 'O'));

>> "OOOOOO"
```

A con of using this method with a `char` is that each primitive is boxed into the `Character` wrapper class, so you might be better of using a `String` instead to produce the same result.

Comment: That would be true if `char` had anything to do with ASCII. It doesn't. Java's text datatypes use the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set.